# Adding code to wp-settings.php/changing table prefix for posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Is it safe to add code to wp-settings.php in WordPress? My main concern is that the file will get rewritten with an update in the future?

I need to be able to share posts between multiple WordPress installs so I am sharing a database and only changing the table prefix for the posts and postmeta tables. I want the table prefix to remain unchanged for everything else. It works fine as long as I place the following code in the wp-settings.php.

```
$wpdb->posts = 'newprefixx_posts';
$wpdb->postmeta = 'newprefix_postmeta';
```

I have not found an action hook that I can use to do this same thing, but if anyone knows of one that would be my preferred method.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a `Wordpress Multisite installation` instead? http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the prefix at runtime by assigning a new value to `$wpdb->prefix`

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Class_Variables

Either way, it is not recommended to make any changes to core files.

You will likely forget what change you made over time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work ok, but I have no idea about the implications of this... The following changes properties inside the global `$wpbd` using a [hook from `wp-settings.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-settings.php#L189).

Create a [Must Use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and add:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom post tables
 */

add_action( 'muplugins_loaded', function(){
    $GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts = 'newprefixx_posts';
    $GLOBALS['wpdb']->postmeta = 'newprefix_postmeta';
});
```